# Initialize cache when it is used

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Lets say that I have the following events:

- DoSomething
- FetchSomething
- FetchSomethingSuccessful

`DoSomething` does something that needs some cached data. When I fire off the event I want to look in the cache and do something with it if it exists. If it doesn't then I want to fetch it, wait for it to be in cache, and try again.

I came up with the following solution but it feels like I'm abusing the `map` operator. **Is there a more appropriate operator to use to observe the stream and throw an error or achieve the effect which is a retry?**

```js
const DO_SOMETHING = 'DO_SOMETHING';
const FETCH_SOMETHING = 'FETCH_SOMETHING';
const FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL = 'FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL';

const events = new Rx.Subject();
const cache = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null);

// the magic sauce
const cacheInitializer = cache
// is there a better way than this?
.map(x => {
  if (!x) { throw 'empty'; }
  return x;
})
.retryWhen(x => {
  console.log('Cache is empty');
  events.next(FETCH_SOMETHING);
  return events.filter(x => x === FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL)
    .first();
});

// fake getting the data
events.filter(x => x === FETCH_SOMETHING)
.do(() => { console.log('Fetching data'); })
.delay(1000)
.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('Data fetched and put into cache');
  cache.next({ data: 1 });
  events.next(FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL);
});

// handle doing something
events.filter(x => x === DO_SOMETHING)
.do(() => { console.log('Check the cache'); })
.switchMapTo(cacheInitializer)
.subscribe(x => {
   console.log('Do something', x);
});

events.next(DO_SOMETHING);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Context:** I am using ngrx and effects. `FETCH_SOMETHING` would trigger another effect and `FETCH_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL` would indicate that the effect completed successfully. My cache in this case is ngrx. I don't think that I would want to cache in the API layer since that would still cause me to update state from the cached response rather than just relying on the data in state.

Answer (score 2):

You want a simple `shareReplay`, but you need rxjs 5.5.0 or later as there was a bug that has been fixed.

```
const cached$ = request$.shareReplay(1);
```

This will trigger the request when the first subscription is made, but subsequent subscriptions will use the cached value.

Errors are passed to the subscriber and then the internal subject is destroyed so that the error itself isn't cached. This makes the observable retryable. So you can attach whatever retry logic you want (such as retrying until successful).

Lastly, the cache also persists if the refCount goes to 0 at some point.

`shareReplay` also takes a second argument, much like the `ReplaySubject` constructor, defining a time window for which to keep the cache.

```js
// Faked request which sometimes errors
const request$ = Rx.Observable
  .defer(() => Rx.Observable.of(Math.random()))
  .do(() => console.log('API called'))
  .map(val => {
    if (val <= 0.3) {
      console.log('API error');
      throw val;
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  })
  .delay(250);

const cached$ = request$.shareReplay(1);

Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .take(5)
  .switchMap(() => cached$.retry(5))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still thinking about how it would practically work in my scenario where I am using ngrx with effects where ngrx is effectively my cache. Unfortunately I loose the benefit of the refCount because subscriptions are on the ngrx store.

Comment: @bygrace Which »refCount benefit«?

Comment: Sorry, I guess you didn't write it but when you wrote about it it reminded me that I can't initiate my http request upon the first subscribe since the subscribe is to the store.

Comment: I appreciate your solution (+1) and it is great for a stand-alone api request. But I don't think it fits my scenario since my cache is external to my stream. I realize that I may have not added enough context in my question to explain why I setup my example the way that I did. I am using ngrx which effectively breaks the stream in half where producers don't know about their actual consumers because ngrx is in the middle.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I haven't used ngrx so I'm not familiar with it and can't say how to make it work with that.

Answer (score 1):

When caching HTTP responses I use something like this:

```
let counter = 1;
const cache$ = new ReplaySubject(1, 1000);

// Mock HTTP request
const http$ = Observable
  .defer(() => Observable.of(counter++).delay(100).do(val => cache$.next(val)))
  .share();

const source$ = Observable
  .merge(cache$, http$)
  .take(1);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/rogetem/9/edit?js,console

It still needs one extra variable `cache$`. I believe it's possible to implement this without it but I think I'd have to use `materialize()` and `dematerialize()` which makes is quite confusing.

You know the cache is empty when the callback for `defer()` is called. Right now it just increments `counter`.

Note, that I still had to use `.do(val => cache$.next(val))` to pass only `next` notifications to the `ReplaySubject` and avoid `error` and `complete` because these would stop the Subject.

You can see that it really works with for example this:

```
source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 0:", val));
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val)), 50);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 60:", val)), 60);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 200:", val)), 200);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1200:", val)), 1200);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val)), 1500);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(val => console.log("Response 3500:", val)), 3500);
```

This prints the following output (each value is cached for 1 second):

```
Response 0: 1
Response 50: 1
Response 60: 1
Response 200: 1
Response 1200: 2
Response 1500: 2
Response 3500: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still thinking about how it would practically work in my scenario where I am using ngrx with effects where ngrx is effectively my cache.

Comment: In my scenario (ngrx + effects) the trigger for needing to initialize the data and check for staleness is an event (`DO_SOMETHING`) rather than a new subscription. Do you think that you could modify this solution to work in that way?